# How to optimize my loading JQuery function?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have sidebar which contains a lot of titles. I don't want to write for all of them a function. Here is a code for one :

```
$("#menu_documentations").click(function () {
$("#sites").load("documentations/documentations_doc.php");
$("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, "slow");
return false;
 });
```

The sidebar's id always look like "#menu_xyz" and the loading php using the same "xyz_doc.php".

How can I avoid to write one by one ?!

Comment: use a class and a data attribute for the url

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use a class and a data attribute for the url 
html:

```
<a class="load-ajax" href="#" data-url="coustom-page-name.html">Link</a>
```

or

```
<a class="load-ajax" href="coustom-page-name.html">Link</a>
```

js:

```
$(".load-ajax").click(function () {
var url = $(this).attr('data-url');//$(this).attr('href');
$("#sites").load(url);
$("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, "slow");
return false;
 });
```

Comment: dont forget the `event.preventDefalt()` if we use an `a` tag.

Comment: @DelightedD0D http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1357118/event-preventdefault-vs-return-false

Comment: Ah, honestly I'm so used to `preventDefault()` I didnt even notice the `return false` :)

Answer (score 0):

The below would work (same as madalin's except I would just use the data attribute itself to target the elements rather than adding another class):

HTML:

```
 <button data-get-page="documentations/documentations_doc.php">click me </button>
```

JS:

```
$(document).on('click','[data-get-page]',function() {
  var $this=$(this);
  var url=$this.data('get-page');
  $("#sites").load(url);
  $("html, body").animate({
    scrollTop: 0
  }, "slow");
  return false;
});
```